# Custom designed view disappeared while using ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I am using one custom designed `CalendarView` in Android. While I am using `Scrollview` in the layout, the custom designed `CalendarView` is not getting displayed in the screen.

what could cause the `CalendarView` to disappear?

My layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/NextMonth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/NextMonth" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/PreviousMonth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/PreviousMonth" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MonthText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Month" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SundayText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/PreviousMonth"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="@string/SundayText"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MondayText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/PreviousMonth"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/SundayText"
            android:text="@string/MondayText"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TuesdayText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/PreviousMonth"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/MondayText"
            android:text="@string/Tuesday"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/WednesdayText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/PreviousMonth"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TuesdayText"
            android:text="@string/Wednesday"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Thursday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/PreviousMonth"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/WednesdayText"
            android:text="@string/ThurdayText"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Friday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/PreviousMonth"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Thursday"
            android:text="@string/FridayText"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Saturday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/PreviousMonth"
            android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Friday"
            android:text="@string/SaturdayText"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <com.example.calendar_module.CalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/NextMonth" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

My CalenderView Class file :

```
package com.example.calendar_module;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.MonthDisplayHelper;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CalendarView extends ImageView {

private static int WEEK_TOP_MARGIN = 0;
private static int WEEK_LEFT_MARGIN = 05;
private static int CELL_WIDTH = 20;
private static int CELL_HEIGH = 20;
private static int CELL_MARGIN_TOP = 05;
private static int CELL_MARGIN_LEFT = 29;
private static float CELL_TEXT_SIZE;

private static final String TAG = "CalendarView"; 
private String[] mDayString = {"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"};
private Calendar mRightNow = null;
private Drawable mWeekTitle = null;
private Cell mToday = null;
private Cell[][] mCells = new Cell[6][7];
private Cell[] mDayCells = new Cell[7];
private OnCellTouchListener mOnCellTouchListener = null;
MonthDisplayHelper mHelper;
Drawable mDecoration = null;

public interface OnCellTouchListener {
    public void onTouch(Cell cell);
    }

public CalendarView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mDecoration = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.typeb_calendar_today);      
    initCalendarView();
}

private void initCalendarView() {
    mRightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    // prepare static vars
    Resources res = getResources();
    WEEK_TOP_MARGIN  = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.week_top_margin);
    WEEK_LEFT_MARGIN = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.week_left_margin);

    CELL_WIDTH = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.cell_width);
    CELL_HEIGH = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.cell_heigh);
    CELL_MARGIN_TOP = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.cell_margin_top);
    CELL_MARGIN_LEFT = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.cell_margin_left);

    CELL_TEXT_SIZE = res.getDimension(R.dimen.cell_text_size);
    // set background
        //      setImageResource(R.drawable.background);
    mWeekTitle = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.calendar_week);

    mHelper = new MonthDisplayHelper(mRightNow.get(Calendar.YEAR), mRightNow.get(Calendar.MONTH));

     }

private void initCells() {

    class _calendar {
        public int day;
        public boolean thisMonth;
        public _calendar(int d, boolean b) {
            day = d;
            thisMonth = b;
        }
        public _calendar(int d) {
            this(d, false);
        }
    };
    _calendar tmp[][] = new _calendar[6][7];

    for(int i=0; i<tmp.length; i++) {
        int n[] = mHelper.getDigitsForRow(i);
        for(int d=0; d<n.length; d++) {
            if(mHelper.isWithinCurrentMonth(i,d))
                tmp[i][d] = new _calendar(n[d], true);
            else
                tmp[i][d] = new _calendar(n[d]);

        }
    }

    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    int thisDay = 0;
    mToday = null;
    if(mHelper.getYear()==today.get(Calendar.YEAR) && mHelper.getMonth()==today.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
        thisDay = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }


    //      // build cells
    Rect Bound = new Rect(CELL_MARGIN_LEFT, CELL_MARGIN_TOP, CELL_WIDTH+CELL_MARGIN_LEFT, CELL_HEIGH+CELL_MARGIN_TOP);
   //       for( int i=0 ; i < 7 ; i++ )
   //       {
   //           
  //            mDayCells[i] = new Cell(mDayString[i],new Rect(Bound),CELL_TEXT_SIZE);
  //            Bound.offset(CELL_WIDTH, 0);
  //            
  //        }
 //     
 //     Bound.offset(0, CELL_HEIGH);      // move to next row and first column
 //     Bound.left = CELL_MARGIN_LEFT;
 //     Bound.right = CELL_MARGIN_LEFT+CELL_WIDTH;
 //     

    for(int week=0; week<mCells.length; week++) {
        for(int day=0; day<mCells[week].length; day++) 
        {

            if(tmp[week][day].thisMonth) {
                if(day==0 || day==6 )
                    mCells[week][day] = new RedCell(tmp[week][day].day, new Rect(Bound), CELL_TEXT_SIZE);
                else 
                    mCells[week][day] = new Cell(tmp[week][day].day, new Rect(Bound), CELL_TEXT_SIZE);
            } else {

                mCells[week][day] = new GrayCell(tmp[week][day].day, new Rect(Bound), CELL_TEXT_SIZE);
            }

            Bound.offset(CELL_WIDTH, 0); // move to next column 

            // get today
            if(tmp[week][day].day==thisDay && tmp[week][day].thisMonth) {
                mToday = mCells[week][day];
                mDecoration.setBounds(mToday.getBound());
            }
        }
        Bound.offset(0, CELL_HEIGH); // move to next row and first column
        Bound.left = CELL_MARGIN_LEFT;
        Bound.right = CELL_MARGIN_LEFT+CELL_WIDTH;

    }       
  }

@Override
public void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
  //        Rect re = getDrawable().getBounds();
 //     WEEK_LEFT_MARGIN = CELL_MARGIN_LEFT = (right-left - re.width()) / 2;
 //     mWeekTitle.setBounds(WEEK_LEFT_MARGIN, WEEK_TOP_MARGIN, WEEK_LEFT_MARGIN+mWeekTitle.getMinimumWidth(), WEEK_TOP_MARGIN+mWeekTitle.getMinimumHeight());

    initCells();
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
}
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(CELL_WIDTH, CELL_HEIGH);
}

 public void setTimeInMillis(long milliseconds) {
    mRightNow.setTimeInMillis(milliseconds);
    initCells();
    this.invalidate();
 }

public int getYear() {
    return mHelper.getYear();
}

public int getMonth() {
    return mHelper.getMonth();
}

public void nextMonth() {
    mHelper.nextMonth();
    initCells();
    invalidate();
}

public void previousMonth() {
    mHelper.previousMonth();
    initCells();
    invalidate();
}

public boolean firstDay(int day) {
    return day==1;
}

public boolean lastDay(int day) {
    return mHelper.getNumberOfDaysInMonth()==day;
}

public void goToday() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    mHelper = new MonthDisplayHelper(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    initCells();
    invalidate();
}

public Calendar getDate() {
    return mRightNow;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(mOnCellTouchListener!=null){
        for(Cell[] week : mCells) {
            for(Cell day : week) {
                if(day.hitTest((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())) {
                    mOnCellTouchListener.onTouch(day);
                }                       
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void setOnCellTouchListener(OnCellTouchListener p) {
    mOnCellTouchListener = p;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // draw background
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mWeekTitle.draw(canvas);

    // draw cells
    for(Cell[] week : mCells) {
        for(Cell day : week) {
            day.draw(canvas);           
        }
    }

    // draw today
    if(mDecoration!=null && mToday!=null) {
        mDecoration.draw(canvas);
    }
}

public class GrayCell extends Cell {
    public GrayCell(int dayOfMon, Rect rect, float s) {
        super(dayOfMon, rect, s);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    }           
}

private class RedCell extends Cell {

    public RedCell(int dayOfMon, Rect rect, float s) {
        super(dayOfMon, rect, s);
        mPaint.setColor(0xdddd0000);
    }           

}


}
```

Comment: I'm guessing when you don't use a ScrollView it works?

Comment: Can you post here the screenshot from what you want to archive? I think you just have to restructure your layout with one or 2 linearlayout.

Comment: @FestusTamakloe : I am not able to upload pictures. I have updated the CalendarView class in the Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, `height` of your custom `view` equals == 0. try to log it. If it is right just override `onMeasure` and set size for your `view`.

And esle : why in xml `height == match_parent`? Can you imagine how it looks in `ScrollView`?)

**UPD:** Ok, in your case `height == 0`. You must `override onMeasure()` method in your custom `view` like this :

```
 @Override
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
     setMeasuredDimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
 }
```

Where width and height values in pixels.

Good luck!

Comment: @llya Demidov : You are correct. I am getting Height as 0 while logging the height of the Calendar View. Can you please tell me what should i do in OnMeasure now?

Comment: I updated my post. If your calendar have static size, just put your constants as width and height. Of course the best way store this constants in xml as dimen. Your view should depends on screen dimension.

Comment: I have updated the CalendarView class in the Question. I have added the line SetMeasuredDimension(CELL_WIDTH,CELL_HEIGH) in the class. But still i am getting the same problem :(

Comment: And what Log talls? Actually you set size 20px\20px. Its not so much. Try to set more for test.

Comment: @llya Demidov : I created two variables CALENDAR HEIGHT, CALENDAR WIDTH and set those values in onMeasure method. But same values cause different results in different size screens.

Comment: different bbecause there are different screens dimension. Add value to xml as <dimen> and take it from there by context.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.id.your_value);